# Open Port \Win 7

Tags: networking, port, bittorrent, utorrent

when doing the download\upload test in UTorrent program it claims my port is not open (Default 17690).

After I plugged my machine directly to the modem (suspect of port forwarding not working), after removing the antivirus I have, and after adding to my firewall inbounds rule regarding to that port, I still fail on the test.

Can you suggest what should be my next examination tests?

Answer (score 0):

Is uTorrent listening on that specific port/interface? Try running a 'netstat' to see for listening connections.

When you connect to your modem, do you get a 'local ip' (is your modem secretly also a router?) or do you get an 'external ip'?

Are you able to connect to other open ports through the internet? (use netstat to find out what ports your computer is listening on, try to connect to those)

Also: http://canyouseeme.org/ is a good tool to use when trying to look for open ports.